# Diophantine applications of Paramodularity

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, diophantine-equations, siegel-modular-forms

I’ve asked this question to quite a few people in person and so far haven’t seen a good answer... but I believe one should exist, so here goes!

Ok, we all know how to (roughly) prove Fermat’s Last Theorem:

Each solution to $a^p + b^p = c^p$ gives a Frey curve, an elliptic curve that is cleverly designed to encode the difference between trivial/non-trivial solutions geometrically (i.e. singular/non-singular Frey curve) and has a very special conductor.

One then invokes modularity in the non-trivial solution case to produce a modular form of a special level... which then is proved to not exist by level lowering arguments. Hence FLT is proved.

One of the current goals for many is to prove paramodularity, which in a nutshell should see certain abelian surfaces correspond to certain genus 2 Siegel modular forms of paramodular level.

The conjecture bas been made precise, for example see Conjecture 1.1.1 of  [this paper](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ejvoight/articles/faltserre-paramodular-073018.pdf).

But anyway the details don’t matter too much. My question is the following naive one: if modularity is to FLT then paramodularity is to what?

Now I am not claiming that paramodularity is useless without Diophantine applications. However I feel it would be nice to know if it can be used to show there is a certain Diophantine equation (or even a family) that has no non-trivial solutions.

Perhaps there is a simple way to generalise the Frey curve construction to give an abelian surface which encodes the triviality/non-triviality of solutions for some Diophantine problem geometrically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arithmetic motivations for modularity in higher rank](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298944/arithmetic-motivations-for-modularity-in-higher-rank)