Consequences of geometric Langlands (or Langlands program) with elementary statements
Undegraduate students often view 90% of research in pure mathematics as something mathematicians do for themselves: no practical applications and even no corollaries understandable to someone who is not a mathematician. I like to give talks and write books (see Theorems of the 21st Century and Landscape of 21st Century Mathematics) that disprove this belief and show that even technical results often have interesting corollaries with easy-to-understand statements. A perfect example is the modularity theorem, which implies Fermat's Last Theorem.
According to Quanta Magazine "Year in Math" review, (which, by the way, came too early: at least one major breakthrough, the proof of The Slice Conjecture (Klartag and Lehec - Affirmative Resolution of Bourgain's Slicing Problem using Guan's Bound, happened later but still in 2024) "arguably the biggest result of 2024" is the proof of the geometric Langlands conjecture.
I would be very interesing to learn whether this proof has any corollaries whose formulation can be easily explained to first-year undegraduates, possibly after introducing some not-too-long preliminary definitions?
If not, maybe the full Langlands program (e.g. Langlands functoriality conjecture) has such  corollaries? In this case, the students can be motivated by a corollary whose statement they could completely understand, and then we say that this remains open but would follow from Langlands program, and the proof of geometric Langlands conjecture is a major milestone towards it.
There are a lot of previous mathoverflow questions on the consequences of Langlands program in general (Consequences of the Langlands program, Results conditional on Langland's conjectures?) and geometric Langlands in particular (Consequences of Geometric Langlands, Implications and consequences of the recent proof of the geometric Langlands conjecture), but it seems to me that none of the corollaries mentioned there has a sufficiently elementary statement.

There's also this question, where Will Sawin gives a pretty similar answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/298944/6518

Just because my work might have practical applications, and corollaries understandable to someone who isn't a mathematician, doesn't disprove that I'm doing it for myself.  (Unless you are reviewing an NSF proposal of mine, in which case practical applications and corollaries understandable to someone who isn't a mathematician are what I think of night and day.)

Ok, imagine a compositor who writes music which only he and a small group of other compositors can truly understand and enjoy. And another situation: he writes mucis that many people can enjoy. This does not disproof that this music was also written "for himself", but if the result is such that many people (not only compositors of his level) can enjoy, this is much better, isn't it?

Imagine a compositor who introduces something that only he and a small group of other compositors can truly understand and enjoy, but which the small group spreads and which ends up revolutionizing music.  That would be even better, wouldn't it?

If the group spreads this to other compositors, and this revolutionize the way they write music, and think about music, this is great. But to call it truly "revolution in music", I think this new way should be able to produce some music that "ordinary" people without musical education can enjoy.

The following is a consequence of the Langlands conjectures. It may not literally be at the first-year undergraduate level but is somewhere in the undergraduate level and far from the top end.
Let $f$ be any polynomial in $n$ variables with integer coefficients. For a prime number $p$ let $$N_f(p) = \# \{x_1,\dots,x_n\in \{0,\dots,p-1\} \mid f(x_1,\dots,x_n) \equiv 0 \mod p\}$$ where $\#$ denotes the number of elements of a set.
Then there exists a polynomial $P$ in one variable with integer coefficients and either we have $P(p)=N_f(p)$ for all but finitely many $P$ or there exists a real number $w$ such that for all real numbers $a,b$ the limit
$$\lim_{X\to \infty} \frac{ \# \{ p<X \textrm{ prime} \mid P(p) + a p^w <N_f(p)< P(p) + b p^w  \} }{\# \{ p<X \textrm{ prime} \}}$$
exists, this limit has the value $1$ for some $a,b$, and there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $b-a<\delta$ then this limit has a value less than $1$.
All of the uses of set builder notation can be replaced by expressing what we are counting in words and clarified  by examples.
The meaning of why I have stated this particular set of conditions can be explained using the concept of a histogram. If we divide the real line into intervals and make a histogram where the height of the bar over each interval is determined by the proportion of $p<X$ such that $\frac{N_f(p)-P(p)}{p^w}$ lies in that interval, then the first condition ensures that the histogram converges as $X \to \infty$, the second condition ensures that the bars of the histogram have total height 1 even if we only draw the bars that can fit on our page, as long as the page is big enough, and the third condition implies there's not just one bar with height 1 and the rest with height 0, as long as the intervals are short enough. So both the last two conditions prevent us from getting a boring histogram in the limit (which we would if we chose the wrong value of $P$ or $w$). Of course, these conditions can also be explained with the concept of a probability measure, but that's less elementary.
This is a version of the generalized Sato-Tate conjecture, stated to be as elementary as I can make it. If I formulated this right, there does not exist any plausible approach to prove this without proving automorphy for all Galois representations arising from algebraic varieties, and one can understand a bit how general that statement is from the statement of the consequence (the fact that it works for any polynomial equation).

Yaakov Baruch askis in the comments if it is possible to give a constructive algorithm to compute $P$ and $w$. I think this is probably possible, but I don't know all the details. Certainly one can do it conditionally on some plausible conjectures. There are two possible approaches to compute them, one elementary and one non-elementary. Let me explain the elementary one.
We compute $N_f(p)$ for many primes $p$, say all primes $p<X$ for $X$ some explicit function of the coefficients of $f$. In case $f=0$ we take $P(p)= p^n$ and we are in the first case. Otherwise, start by setting $P=0$ and $w=n-1$. Iterate the following step:
Compute $s(p)= (N_f(p)-P(p))/p^w$. If the sample variance of $s(p)$ is $>1/2$, terminate the algorithm. Otherwise, if $w$ is an integer, add $p^w$ times the sample average of $s(p)$, rounded to the nearest integer, to $P$, and then regardless of whether $w$ is an integer, subtract $1/2$ from $w$, and repeat.
If $w$ ever gets less than $0$ then terminate in the first case $P(p)=N_f(p)$ for all but finitely many $p$.
This algorithm would always work if we replace the sample variance and the sample average of $s(p)$ by the true variance and average , i.e. the limit as $X\to\infty$ of the sample variance and average. So proving it works is a matter of effectively bounding the rate of convergence of the limit.

Thank you! This answer is better than I expected.

Is this constructive in $P,w$? Would there be a corollary of the corollary all the way down to earth? Maybe for example saying something about primitive roots?

@YaakovBaruch I added some words on constructivity. There certainly are corollaries of the corollaries that are easier to understand in that for many specific values of $f$ I can tell you what $P$ and $w$ should be and even what the limit should be which simplifies the statement. Also for many specific values of $f$ I can give some existential claim like "For each $-4<a<b<4$, there exists $p$ with $N_f(p) \in [ p + a p^{1/2}, p+ b p^{1/2}]$" which again requires Langlands to prove but is simpler.

@YaakovBaruch But it's hard to remove the counting of solutions to polynomial equations in two or more variables from this. (The one variable case is already known, thanks to work of Frobenius - it follows from the weaker form of Chebotarev's density theorem that was proven earlier by Frobenius). In particular, I don't believe there is any application to primitive roots,

Nice, but how does this contradicts the view of "research in pure mathematics as something mathematicians do for themselves"?

@Michael The preamble is phrased in terms of understandability, not just utility: "... no practical applications and even no corollaries understandable to someone who is not a mathematician." And the body of the question is explicitly about understandability: "whether this proof has any corollaries whose formulation can be easily explained to first-year undegraduates."

I do not think that " corollary of the corollary all the way down to earth" is needed here. The statement has a perfect balance between the ease of formulation and generality. The statements for spesific f might be easier but far less general and look artificial. Further, such statements might have easier proofs than the stated general result.

Could you say a bit more about precisely which conjecture this follows from? Not from the result proven by Gaitsgory, Raskin et al, right?

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn Indeed, I meant the classical Langlands conjectures. I was thinking the statement that every Galois representation arising in the cohomology of an algebraic variety corresponds (in the sense of having matching $L$-functions) to an automorphic form on $GL_n$. After writing the answer I realized that it probably suffices to have potential automorphy.

I don't think my remark is "answer worth", so I post as a comment.  There is a gestalt or a wholeness to mathematics and the fact that a specific theorem isn't explainable in an elementary way is, I think, unimportant.  It may be an important stepping stone on the way to a result of real significance that is easy to understand.  Imho, the proof of Fermat had a psychological father in the proof of Mordell-Weil.  Mordel-Weil was certainly a (at worst) grand child of geometric M-W.  Now while explaining geometric M-W in an elementary way seems hard to me, Fermat is obviously easy.
